# masm x86 Assembly How to make a variable point to a value in a set buffer?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Lets say that I've made a simple buffer of about 100 DWORDS, and I also have a variable defined that is supposed to point to a given DWORD in that buffer.

```
.DATA?
buffer DWORD 064h DUP(?)
my_ptr DD ?
```

In the .CODE section, I am trying to get my_ptr to point to, say the first dword in the buffer, so OFFSET buffer + 04h * 00h.
I would think that I could just let a register store the address and then mov the address inside of the register into my_ptr.

```
.CODE
;for the sake of the example pretend that the values in buffer
; are initialized.
MOV EDI, OFFSET buffer
MOV EAX, EDI + 04h * 00h ; trying move the address of the first element in 
;the buffer into EAX
MOV my_var, EAX ;move the address that eax holds into my_var
```

So basically to sum it all up, Is there anyway to make a data variable point to a value inside of a buffer? I do not know if this is possible because every time I've looked at addressing it is always being dereferenced, but I only want the address in this case, and not the value at the address.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.DATA?
buffer DWORD 064h DUP(?)
my_ptr DD ?

.CODE
;for the sake of the example pretend that the values in buffer
; are initialized.
```

It doesn't matter whether they are, as you don't do anything with them in following code.

```
MOV EDI, OFFSET buffer
```

Yes, that's the address (in `edi`) of that reserved memory.

```
MOV EAX, EDI + 04h * 00h ; trying move the address of the first element in 
;the buffer into EAX
```

Now this is not legal in x86 syntax, you can't do `mov reg,reg+immediate`, but as you are adding zero, it's the same thing as `mov eax,edi`, which is legal and would do what you expect, copy the address of array from `edi` to `eax`. Now that's of course useless, as you can store the address directly from the `edi` by: `MOV [my_ptr],edi`

But let's say you want address of third (index 2) DWORD, then your idea of `mov eax, edi + 4*2` can be written like this:

```
mov  eax,edi   ; copy the address first (no math expression possible)
add  eax,4*2   ; offset the address to point to third element
mov  [my_ptr],eax   ; store it
```

But the x86 has more specialized instruction for this, which is allowing you to use the same expressions which are legal for dereferencing (like `mov eax,[edi+4*2]`) only to calculate the address. That instruction is called [`LEA` - load effective address](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_153.html). It works sort of like "`MOV` without guts", so:

```
lea eax,[edi+4*2]
```

will calculate the target memory address, like `MOV`, but instead of contacting memory for the value it will just store the calculated address into destination register, so in this case `eax` will be set to `edi+8` value (and that's address of third element).

This can be used for simple math calculations also, if you forget about the "address" wording from description, like if you want to calculate ecx = eax + 4*edi + 22, then you can do that with single instruction on x86: `lea ecx,[eax + 4*edi + 22]` (but that's possible only because that expression is valid memory operand for `mov` instructions family, if you would want `eax + 5*edi + 22`, you would have to use two `lea` instructions to break that expression into two valid memory addressing expressions, try it on your own as exercise). If you would use only the ordinary arithmetic instructions, you would need four of them (`mov ecx,edi` `shl ecx,2` `add ecx,eax` `add ecx,22`).

Also sometimes you can exploit `lea` to do arithmetic while preserving flags for other ongoing calculation, like incrementing pointers while the CF is reserved for the ongoing addition done over values.

Comment: "`MOV` without guts" Hah! I've never heard that one before. I guess what you're implying is it doesn't have the dereferencing behavior that `MOV` is overloaded with, but it might be kind of confusing because `LEA` is often referred to as a "super" `MOV` because of all the extra arithmetic operations that it can do.

Comment: @CodyGray yeah, I'm looking at it from the HW chip design point of view, where you have the same design as `MOV`, up till the point where dereferencing should happen, then the `LEA` just ends with the address value stored, while the `MOV` has further complex design working out the memory fetch. From the user point of view it may be like you wrote, a "super mov", hm, I never considered this, thanks.